# Will this converge to origin?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, simulation, convergence

- Suppose you have a diffusion of 100 points with the following iteration:

$$(x_{n+1},y_{n+1}) \sim \mathcal{N}\left((x_n,y_n),  \frac{x_n^2 + y_n^2}{2} I_{2 \times2}\right)$$

- This will make a high variance for the points far from the origin and a low variance for the points close to the origin. ( The above equation is just a try to imitate this idea. We can use different equations.)
- I think most of the points will come close to the origin after some time.

#### Question

- Do you also think that?
- Is there any theorem through which we can prove the above?
- Correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: This is a Markov chain. You thus have to find whether or not it has a stationary distribution.

Comment: @Xi'an I read the Markov chain in a discreet setting. Can you give me a reference for further reading?

Comment: I would expect this to tend to move away from the origin on average. Nothing seems to encourage movement towards the origin as each step is in a uniformly random direction, and the typical magnitude of each step tends to bigger when already away from the origin.

Comment: Because this process is scale-invariant, there are only two classes of paths: those that begin at $(0,0)$ (and, obviously, stay there forever) and those that begin elsewhere.  Because the latter include those beginning far beyond the unit disc, and those (intuitively but also obviously) diverge rapidly (compare them to Brownian Motion), the opposite of your conjecture is true.

Comment: Defining $z_n=x_n^2+y_n^2$, this is also a Markov chain such that$$2z_n/z_{n-1}|z_{n-1}\sim\chi^2_2(2)$$Thus on average $z_n$ is twice as large as $z_{n-1}$, and the chain is explosive.

Comment: @Xi'an I like the argument -- reframing the process in terms of $z_n$ certainly is the way to go -- I don't see how the ratio follows a central chi-squared distribution.  Simulated paths diverge, but they don't look "explosive."

Comment: @whuber This is a non-central chi-square, isn't it?

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you for responding -- I misread the notation.  Evidently the "$(2)$" is the non-centrality parameter, so your factor of $2$ comes from $(2+2)/2$ for the conditional expectation.  And indeed, growth of $\log z_n$ is linear.

Comment: [![Matlab code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Lzpx.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Lzpx.png) **Points will diverge**
I have attached an SS of the Matlab code of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my comment of 30 August, since
$$(x_n,y_n)\sim\mathcal N_2((x_{n-1},y_{n-1}),(x_{n-1}^2+y^2_{n-1})\mathbf I_2)$$
we have that
$$\sqrt{2}(x_n,y_n)\big/(x_{n-1}^2+y^2_{n-1})^{1/2}\sim\mathcal N_2(\sqrt{2}(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})/(x_{n-1}^2+y^2_{n-1})^{1/2},\mathbf I_2)$$
and therefore
$$2z_n^2/z_{n-1}=2(x_{n}^2+y^2_{n})/(x_{n-1}^2+y^2_{n-1})=\left|\left|
\sqrt{2}(x_n,y_n)\big/(x_{n-1}^2+y^2_{n-1})^{1/2}
\right|\right|^2$$
is the squared norm of a bivariate Normal vector with identity covariance matrix, hence is distributed as a non-central chi-squared variate with two degrees of freedom:
$$2z_n^2/z_{n-1}\sim\chi^2_2(\left|\left|
\sqrt{2}(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})\big/(x_{n-1}^2+y^2_{n-1})^{1/2}
\right|\right|^2)$$
This distribution simplifies into $\chi^2_2(2)$, which implies that
$$\mathbb E[2Z_n^2/Z_{n-1}]=4$$
hence that
$$\mathbb E[Z_n^2] = 2\mathbb E[ Z_{n-1}]$$
Furthermore,
$$\text{var}(Z_n/Z_{n-1})=\frac{1}{4}(2+2)=1$$
means that the variability of the ratio does not increase with $n$, hence that $Z_n$ diverges almost surely.

Comment: The argument of @whuber (the third comment of my answer) shows that the arguments like $\mathbb E[Z_n^2] = 2\mathbb E[ Z_{n-1}]$ cannot prove $Z_n$ diverges.  So, I don't think your approach is still valid. Please see my other approach.

Answer (score 0):

### **The points move away from the origin.**

We rewrite the dynamic of the point as follows
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
           x_{n+1} \\
           y_{n+1} \\
         \end{pmatrix} 
=\begin{pmatrix}
           x_{n} \\
           y_{n} \\
         \end{pmatrix} 
+ \sqrt{x_n^2 + y_n^2} \cdot \mathcal{N}_2 \left(\begin{pmatrix}
          0\\
           0\\
         \end{pmatrix};\begin{pmatrix}
           1 &0 \\
           0&1 \\
         \end{pmatrix}    \right) 
=\begin{pmatrix}
           x_{n} \\
           y_{n} \\
         \end{pmatrix}  
+ \sqrt{\frac{x_n^2 + y_n^2}{2}} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
           u_{n} \\
           v_{n} \\
         \end{pmatrix} 
$$

where the vectors $(u_n,v_n)'$ are iid and follow the bi-dimensional standard normal distribution. These $(u_n, v_n)_n$ are also independent to $(x_n,y_n)_n$.

Let's denote $r_n = \sqrt{x_n^2 + y_n^2}$ be the distance of the point $n$-th and the origin.

We have
$$\begin{align}
r_{n+1}^2 &= x_{n+1}^2 + y_{n+1}^2 \\
&= \left(x_n + \frac{r_n}{\sqrt{2}}u_n\right)^2 + \left(y_n + \frac{r_n}{\sqrt{2}}v_n\right)^2\\
&= r_n^2 \left(1+   \sqrt{2}\left(\frac{x_n}{r_n}u_n +\frac{y_n}{r_n}v_n \right) + \frac{u_n^2 + v_n^2}{2}\right)
\end{align}$$

We deduce that
$$\frac{r_{n+1}^2}{r_n^2} = 1+   \sqrt{2}\left(\frac{x_n}{r_n}u_n +\frac{y_n}{r_n}v_n \right) + \frac{u_n^2 + v_n^2}{2} \tag{1}$$

From $(1)$, we have:

$$\begin{align}
r_{n+1} \le r_n &\iff \sqrt{2}\left(\frac{x_n}{r_n}u_n +\frac{y_n}{r_n}v_n \right) + \frac{u_n^2 + v_n^2}{2} \le 0 \\
&\iff \left(u_n +\sqrt{2}\frac{x_n}{r_n}  \right)^2+\left(v_n +\sqrt{2}\frac{y_n}{r_n}  \right)^2 \le 2  \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

From $(2)$, we deduce that
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(r_{n+1} \le r_n) &= \mathbb{P}\left( \left(u_n +\sqrt{2}\frac{x_n}{r_n}  \right)^2+\left(v_n +\sqrt{2}\frac{y_n}{r_n}  \right)^2 \le 2  \right) \\
 &= \mathbb{P} (u_n^2 +(v_n-\sqrt{2})^2 \le 2) \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

Indeed, the last equality of $(3)$ is because, geographically, the probability is independently the position of the point $\left(\frac{x_n}{r_n}, \frac{y_n}{r_n}\right)$ lying on the circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$ centered at the origin $O$.

Using Mathematica,

```
NProbability[
 u^2 + (v - Sqrt[2])^2 <= 2, {u, v} \[Distributed] 
  BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 0]]
```

we obtain that
$$\mathbb{P} (u_n^2 +(v_n-1)^2 \le 2) \approx 0.345746 \tag{4}$$

By consequence, from $(3)$ and $(4)$:
$$\color{red}{\mathbb{P}(r_{n+1} \le r_n)  \approx 0.345746 < \frac{1}{2}}\tag{5}$$

---

**However, can we conclude that the points move away from the origin because the probability that $r_{n+1} \le r_n$ is smaller  (less that $0.5$)? No, we can't. Even if the probability that  $r_{n+1} \le r_n$ is smaller, it is possible that whenever $r_{n+1} \le r_n$, the ratio $\frac{r_{n+1}}{r_n}$ may be very small, and then in average, the points come close to the origin.
We need to compute then the expectation of $\frac{r_{n+1}^2}{r_n}$ in case of $r_{n+1} \le r_n$ and in case of $r_{n+1} \ge r_n$ to quantify the movement of the point $n+1$-th in function of the point $n$-th.**

First, we compute the expectation of $\frac{r_{n+1}^2}{r_n} \mathbf{1}_{\{r_{n+1}\le r_n\}}$, from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{r_{n+1}^2}{r_n^2} \mathbf{1}_{\{r_{n+1}\le r_n\}}  \right) &= \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\left(\left(\left(u_n +\sqrt{2}\frac{x_n}{r_n}  \right)^2+\left(v_n +\sqrt{2}\frac{y_n}{r_n}  \right)^2\right) \mathbf{1}_{\{\left(u_n +\sqrt{2}\frac{x_n}{r_n}  \right)^2+\left(v_n +\sqrt{2}\frac{y_n}{r_n}  \right)^2 \le 2\}}  \right)
\end{align}$$
By the same argument as in $(3)$, by rotating the plan $Oxy$, we have:
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{r_{n+1}^2}{r_n^2} \mathbf{1}_{\{r_{n+1}\le r_n\}}  \right) = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E} \left((u_n^2 +(v_n-\sqrt{2})^2)\mathbf{1}_{\{u_n^2 +(v_n-\sqrt{2})^2 \le 2\}}\right)$$

Using Mathematica,

```
NExpectation[
 0.5*(u^2 + (v - Sqrt[2])^2)*
  Boole[u^2 + (v - Sqrt[2])^2 <= 2], {u, v} \[Distributed] 
  BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 0]]
```

We have
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{r_{n+1}^2}{r_n^2} \mathbf{1}_{\{r_{n+1}\le r_n\}}  \right) \approx 0.167714  \tag{5}$$

By similar method, we prove also that
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{r_{n+1}^2}{r_n^2} \mathbf{1}_{\{r_{n+1}\ge r_n\}}  \right) \approx 1.83229  \tag{6}$$

From $(5)$,$(6)$ and $(3)$, by using the definition of conditional expectation, we deduce that
$$\color{red}{\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{r_{n+1}^2}{r_n^2} | r_{n+1}\le r_n  \right)} =\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{r_{n+1}^2}{r_n^2} \mathbf{1}_{\{r_{n+1}\le r_n\}}  \right)}{\mathbb{P}(r_{n+1} \le r_n)}  \approx \frac{0.167714}{0.345746} \color{red}{\approx 0.485079} \tag{7}$$
$$\color{red}{\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{r_{n+1}^2}{r_n^2} | r_{n+1}\ge r_n  \right)} =\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{r_{n+1}^2}{r_n^2} \mathbf{1}_{\{r_{n+1}\ge r_n\}}  \right)}{\mathbb{P}(r_{n+1} \ge r_n)}  \approx \frac{1.83229}{1-0.345746} \color{red}{\approx 2.80057} \tag{8}$$

---

**From $(3), (7), (8)$, we observe that:**

- **Not only : the probability of the event  $\text{reduced} := \{r_{n+1} \le r_n\}$ is smaller than the probability of the event $\text{increased} := \{r_{n+1} \ge r_n\}$**
- **But also: when the event $\text{reduced}$ is realized, the expectation of $\frac{r_{n+1}^2}{r_n^2}$ is only reduced by $0.485079$ (around half) while  the expectation when the event $\text{increased}$ is realized, the increase is $2.80057$ (nearly three times).**

### **We can conclude that for each iteration, the points have a tendency to move away from the origin $O$.**

Comment: The idea is good -- see the comments to the question -- but the algebra is incorrect (you ignored the cross terms when squaring).  It definitely is possible for $r_{n+1}$ to be *less* than $r_n.$

Comment: @whuber I just modified the answer. I think that $r_{n+1}$ is *greater* than $r_n$ in $L_2$.

Comment: That's better, thank you.  But there's a gap: why should an expected ratio exceeding 1 imply the process diverges? To see why this is an issue, consider a (simpler) process in which with probability $1/2$ the ratio is zero and with probability $1/2$ the ratio is $7/2,$ for an expectation of $2.$ Then after $100$ steps (as in the question), the chance that $r_n$ is nonzero is only $2^{-100},$ and almost surely the process terminates at $0$ after a finite number of steps.  What prevents the present process from suffering a similar fate? (Hint: see the last step in Xi'an's answer.)

Comment: @whuber I agree with your comment and modified the anwser. Thank you!